# Conditions for existence of a bounded operator on Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Suppose we have 2 sequences $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$ in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ that are linearly independent and bounded. Is it known under what conditions there is a bounded linear operator $A \colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ such that
$$Af_n=g_n$$
for all n?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible under your general assumptions. Consider the Hilbert space $H=l^2$. Set $g_n=e_n$, $e_n$ the unit sequences. Set $f_1=e_1$ and $f_n=e_1 + n^{-1} e_n$ for $n\ge2$. Assume that there is such a linear mapping with $Af_n=g_n$ for all $n$.
Then $A$ is unbounded: Take $n\ge2$ and compute
$$
Ae_n = A(nf_n-ne_1) = n (e_n-e_1).
$$

---

If one assumes that $(f_n)$ is an orthonormal sequence and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|g_n\|^2<\infty$ then it works. Set
$$
Ax:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,f_n\rangle g_n,
$$
which 
has the desired mapping properties. Moreover,
$$
\|Ax\|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x,f_n\rangle|\cdot \| g_n\|
\le \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\langle x,f_n\rangle|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \| g_n\|^2
\right)^{1/2}  \\
\le \|x\| \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \| g_n\|^2
\right)^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am aware that such operator $A$ won't exist in majority of cases. The question was more about characterization of existence of $A$ in terms of $(f_n)$ and $(g_n)$. Still, your reply was very helpful :)